# Header в одну строчку

Tags: inline, html, display, css

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать header в одну строку.

```
<div id="header_top">
   <div id="address">
       <p>г. Томск, ул. Трифонова, д. 12</p>
   </div><!--end address-->
   <div id="telephone">
       <p>+7 (800) 700 60 50</p>
   </div><!--end telephone-->
   <div id="search">
           <img src="img/search.png" alt="Форма поиска по сайту"/>
   </div><!--end search-->
</div><!--end header_top-->
```

Какие свойства задать в css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#header_top div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

ИЛИ

для каждого внутреннего дива проставьте класс, по которому сделаете у него inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxLr629v/1/

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. :)

Comment: @Daryushka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).